# Some images disappeared from text message group chat

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I use an iPhone SE, not with iTunes on my Windows laptop because it is far too heavy an app and doesn't do all the syncing I need with Outlook.

I normally don't log into my Apple cloud account and wish to continue to operate like this.  I use SMS and MMS rather than iMessage.  Since I am sharing text and images with multiple users at the same time, I am assuming that the protocol is MMS.  The conversation thread for this group is ongoing, over months.

Yesterday evening, one member of the group shared an image, which I could see.  Today, I can see the text portion, but there is no indication that there was ever an image associated with the message.  Older images further up in the group conversation are present, as is a newer one shared more recently today.

***What would cause images to so selectively disappear?  How can I prevent this?  Is there a way to get the image back?***

From what I could find online, possible explanations are not enabling MMS or running out of room.  Neither of these explain fit the observations above.

Comment: This is why we use Signal.  It’s encrypted messaging let me know I if you want it set up

Comment: My bro + step-sister are exhorting me to join the dark side: WhatsApp.  I'm resisting because one reason for getting an iPhone (which is very unnatural for me, being Windows and Android oriented) is because I don't like the security implications of installing an app for every single little thing.  I use mostly native apps in iOS.  If it doesn't reliably support something as basic as MMS, I need to rethink that whole strategy.  I'm trying to get a bead on where the problem lies.

Comment: did the OP delete it

Comment: It's not in the cloud, so I don't think that's an option.  As well, another recipient in the group was able to take a screen shot of it and CC it to me, so it was still present on his phone (not an iPhone).